# Enity Framework Core Mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am facing an issue with the mapping in the Entity Framework. Initially My model is like

```
public class Model1 
{
  public string[] Fields
  { get; set; }
}
```

so that the data saved in db is like ["data1","data2"]. Now as per new requirement my model got changed as below

```
public class Model1 
{
 public Model2[] Fields
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}

public class Model2 
{
public string prop1 {get;set;}
public string prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

For the new implementation new saving is working fine. But for the existing records while fetching the data getting type casting issue.

Cannot convert string array to model2 array.

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: It may be not possible with code-first , I think you need to migrate old data first into new schema at DB level

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, this is already in production, hence i cannot make changes at all DB's. Expecting code side solution only.

Comment: Is your new model already in production? Can you run ef migration in production ?

Comment: I store the data as a JSON in the db in a single column. My issue is with the mapping only not with the Database schema.

Answer (score 0):

All right. You need to keep the same entity for Model1 but just adding getters:

```
public class Model1 
{
  public string[] Fields { get; set; }

  public string prop1 { get { return Field[0]; } }
  public string prop2 { get { return Field[1]; } }
}
```

Then you can create a method only for migration purpose where you fetch all your Model1 data, you translate them into Model2 and your save them. It looks like:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    foreach( var model1 in context.SetModel1 )
    {
        context.SetModel2.Add(
            new Model2() { prop1 = model1.prop1, prop2 = model1.prop2 }
        );
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```